# Sed command not executing correctly

Tags: bash, sed

I'm new to Bash and trying to modify a file using `sed`. Consider this simple example:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob
file="/root/test.txt"

# Modify the file.
sed "s/apple/orange/g" $file -> $file.tmp && mv $file.tmp $file
```

I run the script, and it hangs. Looking at the directory:

```
ls
test.sh test.txt test.txt.tmp
```

Shows `test.txt.tmp` is created, but `mv` is not working.

What is wrong with the script?

Comment: `->` should be `>`

Comment: also, use `sed -i ${file}` or `sed ${file} | sponge ${file}` instead of that...

Comment: if the `mv` isn't happening, then `sed` is returning non-zero... have you checked what it returns?

Comment: `${file}.tmp` will be created by the shell (not `sed`)... so it'll be created no matter what, and may well have a size of `0`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the following line:

```
sed "s/apple/orange/g" $file -> $file.tmp && mv $file.tmp $file
```

Bash interprets this line as:

```
sed "s/apple/orange/g" $file - > $file.tmp && mv $file.tmp $file
```

Notice the subtle difference (the space between `-` and `>`).

Now, what is happening? The `-` <hyphen> is interpreted to be a file. More specifically `/dev/stdin`. This implies that `sed` is awaiting input from `/dev/stdin`. That is also the reason why it is hanging. It is actually not hanging but awaiting input. The file `$file.tmp` is created, but since the `sed` command is still executing, the `mv` is not happening.

> The standard input shall be used if no file operands are specified, and shall be used if a file operand is `-` and the implementation treats the `-` as meaning standard input. Otherwise, the standard input shall not be used. See the INPUT FILES section.
>
> **<sub>source: [POSIX sed standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)</sub>**

Also related: [Usage of a dash in place of a filename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16357/usage-of-dash-in-place-of-a-filename)